# rdesktop is not accepting a 3 key combination

Tags: keyboard, remote-desktop

So I'm using `rdesktop` to connect to a remote server of us where I have Visual Studio. The virtual machine is a Windows 2008 server. I use this parameters:

```
rdesktop -D -g 1920x1200 -k it X.X.X.X
```

Because I have an Italian keyboard. I have no problem writing, the keys are in place. When I try to type `{` or `}` I have problems because with the italian keyboard I have this combination: <kbd>L-Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+(<kbd>è</kbd>|<kbd>+</kbd>)

and it's not working

Do you have a solution by any chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit `/usr/share/rdesktop/keymaps/it`:

Search these lines:

```
braceleft 0x08 altgr
braceright 0x0b altgr
```

And change to:

```
braceleft 0x1a shift altgr
braceright 0x1b shift altgr
```

Answer (score 0):

The above fix has now been committed upstream of rdesktop project and will
be included in the next release 1.7.2